# Is there a difference between na.rm = FALSE and na.ram = na.rm?

Tags: r

in sum() and mean(), na.rm = TRUE has the function ignore any NA values.

if na.rm = FALSE, the function includes the NA values in the calculation.

```
    sum_to_one <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
    x / sum(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    }
```

This comes from R4DS, learning about functions and setting na.rm to true or false in the input. THe above code is supposed to be the same as

```
     x / sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But the na.rm is TRUE in the original expression, but in the function it is set to na.rm = FALSE in the function input and then na.rm = na.rm in the sum() expression.

I'm seeing that it is better practice to do 
        function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {} 
in general to allow the user to change it and to be consistent with default settings for sum and mean. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many base functions (base as in base R or base to any particular package) accept the argument `na.rm=`, where the default is often `FALSE`. (Some functions use `useNA=` or `na.action`, depending on different actions, but we'll ignore those.)

Higher-level functions (user-defined and/or other packages) might also define this argument and then pass it on to the other functions. For example:

```r
parent_func <- function(x, ..., na.rm = FALSE) {
  # something important
  mu <- mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  sigma <- sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  (mu - x) / sigma
}
```

One premise being that if you intend to remove/ignore `NA` values for one portion of the function, you might use it in other places (or all).

In this case, in the call to `mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)`, the *left* `na.rm` is referring to the argument named `na.rm` in the definition of `mean`. The *right* `na.rm` is referring to the same-named argument of `parent_func`.

An alternative way to define this parent function (for the sake of differentiating variables) could be:

```r
parent_func <- function(x, ..., NARM = FALSE) {
  # something important
  mu <- mean(x, na.rm = NARM)
  sigma <- sd(x, na.rm = NARM)
  (mu - x) / sigma
}
```

The advantage of using `na.rm=` instead of this `NARM=` is likely consistency (though that is not always one of R's strengths across all functions). Many users are likely more intuitively familiar with the `na.rm=` argument name, purpose, and effect than something else.

**Edit**:

> I'm seeing that it is better practice to do function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {} in general to allow the user to change it and to be consistent with default settings for sum and mean. Is this correct?

I believe so. In general I find that removal of missing data should be an explicit act by the user, not a default by the function. That is, if having missing data indicates a larger problem, then defaulting to `na.rm=FALSE` will quickly indicate to the user that something is wrong; `na.rm=TRUE` will mask this problem and suggest valid results when perhaps there should be no `NA`s at all. This holds true for the "smaller" functions (e.g., `mean`, `sum`) and so its logic should be carried outwards to the encapsulating functions.